# CSS selector to select last TD which does not have 'hide' class in its row

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table row with TD , each TD element has 'm-rowcell' class and some cells are hidden by using 'm-hide' class.

I need to select last TD element Which is not have 'm-hide' class by using only CSS.

```css
.m-hide {
  display: none;
}
.m-rowcell {
  border: 1px solid;
}
tr td:last-child { /*visible last child*/
  background: #FFAA33;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr class="m-row">
    <td class="m-rowcell">Header 1</td>
    <td class="m-rowcell">Header 2</td>
    <td class="m-rowcell m-hide">Header 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="m-rowcell">content 1</td>
    <td class="m-rowcell">content 2</td>
    <td class="m-rowcell m-hide">content 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="m-row">
    <td class="m-rowcell">content 1</td>
    <td class="m-rowcell">content 2</td>
    <td class="m-rowcell m-hide">content 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="m-row">
    <td class="m-rowcell">content 1</td>
    <td class="m-rowcell">content 2</td>
    <td class="m-rowcell m-hide">content 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to do this?

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7m6h1ax/)

Comment: If you are asking to us, if you can remove the class hide from the last TD element then no you cannot, you can do this with JQuery or Javascript. If this is not what you are asking, could you please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

EDITED AFTER QUESTION REPHRASE

You can't do that with only css.
CSS can reach last element of its parent, last element of its type but can't go back to its previous sibling without affecting all others.
You can do that by cycling in javascript/jquery or just adding a specific class to those td you want select.